# Javascript in need of simplification - collapsible tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've coded some tabs and it seems to work well, although I'm sure I can achieve this with much cleaner code! I'm just not sure how to do that at the moment. I would really appreciate some help with this one.

I'm not sure if its loops I want to use or something completely different?

The way I've done it obviously works but it just seem unnecessary and messy, after this the next step is to add in a transition effect as the tabs come down. I'm not sure if this will even allow me to do that.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("results1");
  var b = document.getElementById("results2");
  var c = document.getElementById("results3");
  var d = document.getElementById("title1"); 
  var e = document.getElementById("title2"); 
  var f = document.getElementById("title3"); 
  if (a.style.display === "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    d.style.backgroundColor = "#005FAA";
    e.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
    f.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  } 
  else {
    a.style.display = "none";
    d.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var a = document.getElementById("results1");
  var b = document.getElementById("results2");
  var c = document.getElementById("results3");
  var d = document.getElementById("title1"); 
  var e = document.getElementById("title2"); 
  var f = document.getElementById("title3"); 
  if (b.style.display === "none") {
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "none";
    d.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
    e.style.backgroundColor = "#005FAA";
    f.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  } 
  else {
    b.style.display = "none";
    e.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var a = document.getElementById("results1");
  var b = document.getElementById("results2");
  var c = document.getElementById("results3");
  var d = document.getElementById("title1"); 
  var e = document.getElementById("title2"); 
  var f = document.getElementById("title3"); 
  if (c.style.display === "none") {
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "block";
    d.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
    e.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
    f.style.backgroundColor = "#005FAA";
  } 
  else {
    c.style.display = "none";
    f.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  }
}
```

```css
body{
margin: 10px;}

.title{
background-color:lightgrey;
width: 32%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
margin-right: 2%;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.title:last-child{
margin-right:0px;
width:32%;}

.results{
background-color:#005FAA;
float:left;
width: 100%;
color: white;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="title1" class="title" onclick="myFunction()">
        <h4>Item 1</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title2" class="title" onclick="myFunction1()">
        <h4>Item 2</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title3" class="title" onclick="myFunction2()">
        <h4>Item 3</h4>
    </div> 
</div>


<div class="results" id="results1" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="results" id="results2" style="display:none">Item 2</div>
<div class="results" id="results3" style="display:none">Item 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible clean-up:

```js
function myFunction(title) {
  var results = [...document.getElementsByClassName("results")]
  results.forEach(function(r) {
    if (title.dataset.for == r.id) {
      r.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      r.style.display = "none";
    }    
  });

  var titles = [...document.getElementsByClassName("title")]
  titles.forEach(function(t) {
    if (t == title) {
      t.style.backgroundColor = "#005FAA"
    } else { 
      t.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey"
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
margin: 10px;}

.title{
background-color:lightgrey;
width: 32%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
margin-right: 2%;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.title:last-child{
margin-right:0px;
width:32%;}

.results{
background-color:#005FAA;
float:left;
width: 100%;
color: white;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="title1" data-for="results1" class="title" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h4>Item 1</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title2" data-for="results2" class="title" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h4>Item 2</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title3" data-for="results3" class="title" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h4>Item 3</h4>
    </div> 
</div>


<div class="results" id="results1" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="results" id="results2" style="display:none">Item 2</div>
<div class="results" id="results3" style="display:none">Item 3</div>
```

I replaced your three functions with one function that accepts a parameter representing the title element.  In the event handler, we just pass `this` to that function.  Then in the function, we loop over the things that might have to change (the `title` and `results` nodes) testing as we do whether we're working with the matching element or a different one and choosing behavior based on that.

To link the `title` elements with the `results` one, I add a `data-for` attribute to it.  There are many other ways this could be done, including using regular expressions to find the basic id (`title2 ~> 2`, `results2 ~> 2` for instance) and matching on those.  But this should get you going.

There is more clean-up I would probably do on this, but this should offer significant simplification.

### Update

A comment pointed out that the above did not allow for total tab deselection.  Given that, it seems better to refactor a bit more and use the shared base id approach.  Here is another version written that way:

```js
function myFunction(title) {
  var id = title.id.match(/^\D*(\d+)$/)[1]
  var hidden = document.getElementById(`results${id}`).style.display !== 'block';

  [...document.getElementsByClassName("results")].forEach(function(r) {
    r.style.display = "none";    
  });
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("title")].forEach(function(t) {
    t.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  });

  if (hidden) {
    document.getElementById(`results${id}`).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(`title${id}`).style.backgroundColor = '#005FAA';
  }
}
```

```css
body{
margin: 10px;}

.title{
background-color:lightgrey;
width: 32%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
margin-right: 2%;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.title:last-child{
margin-right:0px;
width:32%;}

.results{
background-color:#005FAA;
float:left;
width: 100%;
color: white;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="title1" class="title" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h4>Item 1</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title2" class="title" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h4>Item 2</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title3" class="title" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h4>Item 3</h4>
    </div> 
</div>


<div class="results" id="results1" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="results" id="results2" style="display:none">Item 2</div>
<div class="results" id="results3" style="display:none">Item 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - although this doesn't allow the tabs to be deselected which is critical for what I need it for

Comment: @JamieRicketts: Added an updated version which does allow this total deselection.  It's probably still cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? You are already using JQuery, so maybe make it modular and use it to help with your transition down effects (you can transition them up too if you'd like).

```js
const tabs = {
  animating: false,
  toggleResults: function(thatTab) {
    const thatResult = $(`[data-title="${thatTab.attr('id')}"]`);
    thatTab.toggleClass('activeTab');
    thatResult.toggleClass("openedResult");
    tabs.animating = true;
    thatResult.slideToggle("fast", function() {
      tabs.animating = false;
    });
  },
  init: function() {
    $(".title").click(function() {
      const thatTab = $(this);
      const openedResult = $('.openedResult');
      const thatTabId = thatTab.attr("id");
      const openedResultTitle = openedResult.data('title');

      if (!tabs.animating) {
        $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab');
        openedResult.removeClass('openedResult').hide();
        if (thatTabId !== openedResultTitle) {
          tabs.toggleResults(thatTab);
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  tabs.init();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-basis: 32%;
  transition: background-color 0ms;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.activeTab {
  background-color: #005faa;
  transition: background-color 100ms;
}

.results {
  background-color: #005faa;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="title1" class="title">
    <h4>Item 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="title2" class="title">
    <h4>Item 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="title3" class="title">
    <h4>Item 3</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="results" data-title="title1">Item 1</div>
<div class="results" data-title="title2">Item 2</div>
<div class="results" data-title="title3">Item 3</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP is already using jQuery?  I see no sign of that.

Comment: In the first version of this question, I thought I saw a JQuery CDN in a script tag, but it's not there anymore. I could rewrite this suggestion in Vanilla JS.

Comment: That makes sense.  I don't think it was actually there; I believe my moving of the code to a snippet was the only edit.  But if that's what you thought, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , you can call same function on all three divs with passing their ids to find the current id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">

body{
margin: 10px;}

.title{
background-color:lightgrey;
width: 32%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
margin-right: 2%;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.title:last-child{
margin-right:0px;
width:32%;}

.results{
background-color:#005FAA;
float:left;
width: 100%;
color: white;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.active{
  display = "block"
}
.inactive{
  display : "none"
  backgroundColor:"#005FAA"
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div id="title1" class="title" onclick="ActivateTab(1)">
        <h4>Item 1</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title2" class="title" onclick="ActivateTab(2)">
        <h4>Item 2</h4>
    </div> 
    <div id="title3" class="title" onclick="ActivateTab(3)">
        <h4>Item 3</h4>
    </div> 
    <button onclick="ActivateTab(2)">Test</button>
</div>


<div class="results" id="results1" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="results" id="results2" style="display:none">Item 2</div>
<div class="results" id="results3" style="display:none">Item 3</div>

<script> 

function ActivateTab(id){
  let results = document.querySelectorAll(".results")
  let titles = document.querySelectorAll(".title")

  results.forEach((elementResut,index) =>{
    let elementTitle = titles[index];
      if(elementResut.id === "results"+id 
      && elementResut.style.display === "none")
      {
            elementResut.style.display = "block";
            elementTitle.style.backgroundColor = "#005FAA";
      }
      else{
        elementResut.style.display = "none";    
        elementTitle.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
      }
  }); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: This isnt working in IE. Undefined variable, I can't figure out why that might be?

Comment: I've solved this now - You can't use arrow functions with IE and the forEach needed to be changed also